# doctype' is an unexpected token error

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, doctype

Recently users who are using my .NET application encountered some problems regarding this error message while running: `doctype' is an unexpected token. the expected token is 'doctype'`.

Interesting thing is that only few out of the hundreds people encountered this problem.

This is how my XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<build>
    <row>
        <car>Type</car>
        <enum>12</enum>
    </row>
    <row>
        <car>Type1</car>
        <enum>14</enum>
    </row>
    <row>
        <car>Type2</car>
        <enum>15</enum>
    </row>
</build>
```

What I am actually doing in the .NET application is a loop through the XML elements and displaying the `<car>` on each loop.

I've been trying recommend people installing the latest .NET Framework library but this doesn't help.

What is causing this error and how could it be fixed?

## edit

vb.net snippet of code:

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Dim data As String = client.DownloadString("http://mywebsite.com/code.php")

While client.IsBusy
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
End While

Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(data)

For Each row As System.Xml.XmlElement In list
    'proceed the element(s)...
Next
```

^ code.php , which is responsible for the output XML string:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8;');
ini_set('default_mimetype', "text/xml");
ini_set('default_charset', "utf-8");

echo "<?xml version='1.0'?>
<build>";
foreach ($_engine as $line)
{
    echo '<row><car>' . htmlspecialchars($line->car) . '</car><enum>' . (int)$line->enum . '</enum></date></row>';
}
echo "</build>";
?>
```

Comment: I'd suggest posting the relevant snippet of code, as the XML is well-formed and wouldn't appear to be the problem.

Comment: You have to give use a way to reproduce the problem. Otherwise I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: @Marcinjuraszek To be honest, I couldnt even reproduce this problem myself. As I said, only few out of the hundreds users expierence this problem. I've been trying to reproduce this, but failed...

Comment: Btw. I am producing the XML code via PHP I will edit my question soon and will add more code.

Comment: Updated the code. Added snippets of PHP and vb.net codes.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this error by adding the following line after `<?xml version='1.0'?>`:

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd xhtml 1.1//en" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml11/dtd/xhtml11.dtd">
```

This will throw an error:

> 'doctype' is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'DOCTYPE'

Note that the expected token is `DOCTYPE` in uppercase. I believe that the returned XML file somehow contains this element. You could try to remove everything before and after the root element like this:

```
Const startTag As String = "<build>"
Const endTag As String = "</build>"

Dim startIndex As Integer = data.IndexOf(startTag, 0, data.Length, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
Dim endIndex As Integer = If((startIndex > -1), data.LastIndexOf(endTag, (data.Length - 1), data.Length), -1)

If ((startIndex > -1) AndAlso (endIndex > -1)) Then
    data = ("<?xml version='1.0'?>" & Environment.NewLine & data.Substring(startIndex, ((endIndex - startIndex) + endTag.Length)))
End If
```

And then load the XmlDocument:

```
Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(data)
```